# HTTP Handler Restricting Files to be only Readonly / View Only instead of Downloadable C# ASP.NET WebPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download, httphandler

I have a client with an online files Library. 
She wants to be able to make some of her files in the forms library "ReadOnly".

Right now all the files display when you view the files library page.

When you click on a file, it opens the standard browser window and asks you if you want to open or download the file. Basically she wants to limit some of the files to only allow you to open and not download the file.

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, since this is kind of a user preference browser setting type thing but I figured I'd get some input before I tell her know.

Right now I'm using an asp.net HTTP Handler I wrote called file handler.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (this.FileName != null)
        {
            string path = String.Concat(ConfigurationManager.UploadsDirectory, this.FileName);
            string contentType = Utility.IO.File.GetContentType(this.FileName);

            if (File.Exists(path) == true)
            {
                context.Response.Buffer = true;
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("inline; filename={0}", (Url.Encode(this.DisplayFileName))));
                context.Response.TransmitFile(path);
                context.Response.Flush(); 
                context.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "File Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
```

This function(Utility.IO.File.GetContentType) is a simple utility function I use to get the content type based on file extention.

Anyways, is there anything I can change in this code to make it so the file is readonly or "View Only". Maybe some type of header I can add?

Comment: Any resource that can be opened can also be downloaded.  Is this a question about usability or security?  If the latter, give up.

Comment: No.
If I open a file from the web, all of the data is on my computer, so I can edit, save, etc. it.

Comment: Remind your client that "read-only" content-type such as text/html is easily downloaded with right-click->save as

Comment: Can `this.FileName` somehow be altered by user supplied input? What happens with a name of `..\..\web.config` or similar?

Comment: I obviously know that there is no way to complete protect the files, anything available in the browser is stored on your machine no matter what you do with it, but I'm just hoping to have something I can bring back to the client that has the "illusion", for lack of better word, that it's being made "ReadOnly" or "ViewOnly". Basically, i just need to give the client "something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. This was not possible to do.